# Find input value inside child div

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html structure:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        <input type="text" value="Hello World...">
        <div class="subContent">
            <button id="myButton">Get Input Value</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <input type="text" value="Hello World...">
        <div class="subContent">
            <button id="myButton">Get Input Value</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the button click get the value of the closest input! 
I can't use class or id because this elements will reoccur with the same classname!

I tried something like:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input').val();
});
```

But I was unsuccessful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. `.parent()` only goes up one level (to the parent). Instead, you could change that to [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Ex:

```
$(this).closest('div.content').find('input').val();
```

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    console.log( $(this).closest('div.content').find('input').val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        <input type="text" value="Hello World...">
        <div class="subContent">
            <button id="myButton">Get Input Value</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <input type="text" value="Hello World...">
        <div class="subContent">
            <button id="myButton">Get Input Value</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. You could also chain the `.parent()` calls to go up the DOM far enough (e.g. `.parent().parent()`), but it's not recommended. `.closest()` is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You could to use `.parents('selector')` note the `s` at the end and the selector passed as parameter :

```
$(this).parents('div.content').find('input').val();
```

Code:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    console.log( $(this).parents('div.content').find('input').val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        <input type="text" value="Hello World...">
        <div class="subContent">
            <button id="myButton">Get Input Value</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <input type="text" value="Hello World...">
        <div class="subContent">
            <button id="myButton">Get Input Value</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```